# MySQL - Foreign Key does not work even when InnoDB is on (Ubuntu 16.04)(Error code: 1215)

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, foreign-keys, innodb

I am having a problem with an text-book example of MySQL table. 
**The trick is, it works on Windows OS but for some strange reason , it does not work for Linux.** I tried configuring the default engine and it is InnoDB for sure, bot for some strange reason it still isn't working.

```
CREATE TABLE radnik(
     Mbr integer NOT NULL,
     Ime varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     Prz varchar(25) NOT NULL,
     Sef integer,
     Plt decimal(10, 2),
     Pre decimal(6, 2),
     God date NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT radnik_PK PRIMARY KEY (Mbr),
     CONSTRAINT radnik_FK FOREIGN KEY (Sef) REFERENCES radnik (Mbr),
     CONSTRAINT radnik_CH CHECK (Plt>500)    
)engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE projekat(
     Spr integer NOT NULL,
     Ruk integer NOT NULL,
     Nap varchar(50),
     Nar varchar(50),
     CONSTRAINT projekat_PK PRIMARY KEY (Spr),
     CONSTRAINT projekat_FK FOREIGN KEY (Ruk) REFERENCES radnik (Mbr),
     CONSTRAINT projekat_UK UNIQUE (Nap)
)engine=innodb;
CREATE TABLE radproj(
     Spr integer NOT NULL,
     Mbr integer NOT NULL,
     Brc integer NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT radproj_PK PRIMARY KEY (Spr, Mbr),
     CONSTRAINT radproj_rad_FK FOREIGN KEY (Mbr) REFERENCES radnik(Mbr),
     CONSTRAINT radproj_prj_FK FOREIGN KEY (Spr) REFERENCES projekat(Spr)
);
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: Error 1215, cannot add foreign key contraint

Comment: `CHECK` is recognized by MySQL, but ignored.  MySQL's sibling, MariaDB, does process `CHECK`:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/constraint_type-check-constraint/ , but only since 10.2.1 (7/2016); see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/check-constraints-support/

Answer (score 0):

For a self-referencing foreign key, I don't think you can put the foreign key constraint in the `CREATE TABLE` statement. You have to create the table first, then add the constraint with `ALTER TABLE`.

This works for me.

```
CREATE TABLE radnik(
     Mbr integer NOT NULL,
     Ime varchar(20) NOT NULL,
     Prz varchar(25) NOT NULL,
     Sef integer,
     Plt decimal(10, 2),
     Pre decimal(6, 2),
     God date NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT radnik_PK PRIMARY KEY (Mbr)  
)engine=innodb;

ALTER TABLE radnik ADD CONSTRAINT radnik_FK FOREIGN KEY (Sef) REFERENCES radnik (Mbr);
```

BTW, MySQL ignores `CHECK` constraints.

Comment: IT WORKS! Thanks a lot .
But it is still a mystery to me, why the heck it works for Windows like the way it is and not on Linux.

Comment: Are you running a different MySQL version?

Comment: Did not have a excess to the Win PC so I could not check the correct version. Probably the mysql-server from Ubuntu packages are not the newest. Could tell because the next error I got when I tried to update the table: Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

EDIT: It is the newest version of mysql. The Win PC are on the newest version so version is not a problem.

Comment: Fixed it , I guess the textbook error was not very well written.